# Images not center aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, github, alignment, github-pages

sorry if this is a simple or silly issue.

Essentially I'm trying to centre align all the images on my page, however the alignment isn't working as I want, you can see on my [site here](http://flimsy.site/nikki). This is the CSS I'm using for the three main sections. They align centre, but they use the left side of each image, rather than the middle of the image being the focal.

```
.links {
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
}
.footer {
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
top: 75%;
left: 50%;
}
.header {
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
top: 25%;
left: 50%;
}
```

Due to not being able to post more than 2 links, you can find the **nikki.html** and **style.css** here if you need to see more: https://github.com/Flimmykins/Flimmykins.github.io

I tried changing the left percentage to manually do it myself, but that made the site display oddly on different things. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you using a fixed position for everything? `body { text-align: center;}` seems to be all you need.

Comment: Removing fixed position corrects the horizontal alignment issue, but it then causes the "top: 50%" etc vertical spaces to seemingly be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can try : `display: block` for the `img` inside your `div`
This will allow you to center it horizontally.

Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Block elements are not friendly with alignments. `img` tag is an `inline` element by default. The type that can be aligned simply with just `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
.center-custom {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

then just put the class="center-custom" attribute inside your img element.